# Rename all directories reversing date string name delimited by hyphens

Tags: sed, terminal, rename

I have subdirectories named as dates like `09 January 2020`. I renamed all the directories to replace spaces with hyphens using the terminal command:

```
$ for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g'`"; done
```

Now I get subdirectories named as `09-January-2020`.
I want to reverse the date order and get subdirectories named as `2020-January-09`. I want to use the same for-loop as above but different sed command to reverse the order of date format in the name of subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` to create the new names for your directories:

```
for d in *; do
    echo mv -- "$d" "$(echo "$d" | sed -E 's/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/\3-\2-\1/')"
done
```

The matched parts inside parentheses are being reused into the replacement in reversed order. Remove the first `echo` after testing.